# null is not an object in component state in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I'm trying to implement [react-native-modal-datetime-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal-datetime-picker) in my app

**Source code**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
    import {
      View,
      ScrollView,
      DatePickerIOS,
      TouchableOpacity,
      Text,
      TextInput,
      Button,
      StyleSheet
    } from "react-native";
    import RBSheet from "react-native-raw-bottom-sheet";
    import data from "./static.json";

import DateTimePicker from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker'; 

export default class App extends React.Component {

 constructor (props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
     cdate: '',
     setDate: '',
     isVisible: false,
     setVisible: false,

  };

  render() {

  const { cdate, isVisible, setDate, setVisible } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.textTitle}>REACT NATIVE RAW BOTTOMSHEET</Text>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>

          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.Scrollable.open()} style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>SCROLLABLE</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>     
        </View>

        {/* Grid Menu */}
        <RBSheet
          ref={ref => {
            this.Scrollable = ref;
          }}
          closeOnDragDown
          customStyles={{
            container: {
              borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
              borderTopRightRadius: 10
            }
          }}
        >
          <ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.gridContainer}>
             <DateTimePicker
  mode="time"
  isVisible={isVisible}
  cdate={cdate}
  onConfirm={cdate => {
    setDate(cdate.toTimeString());
    setVisible(false);
  }}
  onCancel={() => this.setState({ setVisible: false })}
/>
            </View>

          </ScrollView>
        </RBSheet>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
  },
  textTitle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    marginTop: 120
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 50
  },
  button: {
    width: 150,
    backgroundColor: "#4EB151",
    paddingVertical: 10,
    alignItems: "center",
    borderRadius: 3,
    margin: 10
  },

});
```

This is the error I'm getting

[image]

> Unexpected token, expected ";" (31:11)
>
> 29 |   };   30 |
>
> > 31 |   render() {
> >          |            ^   32 |   33 |   const { cdate, isVisible, setDate, setVisible } = this.state;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says it all you missed a close bracket

```
constructor (props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         cdate: '',
         setDate: '',
         isVisible: false,
         setVisible: false,

      }
  }  // here

  render() {

  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_this$state.cdate') component state object: const { cdate, isVisible, setDate, setVisible } = this.state;

It's because you are destructuring and using an object called `this.state` in render() function

```
const { cdate, isVisible, setDate, setVisible } = this.state;
```

And you forgot to declare the state above. Add the following state in your component -

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  //add other states too that you are using and assign them your initial values//
  this.state = {
    cdate: "",
    isVisible: "",
    setDate: "",
    setVisible: "",
  }

  render() {
```

Comment: Unexpected token, expected ";" (31:11)

  29 |   };
  30 |
> 31 |   render() {
     |            ^
  32 |
  33 |   const { cdate, isVisible, setDate, setVisible } = this.state;   I get this error  (I updated the source code)